# How to use a nested serialize for serializing and deserializing data? django-rest-framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have following serializers:

```
class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'password')


class ProfileSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'name', 'address')
```

when I want to create a profile I should send following data:

```
{
    "user":{
        "username": "test_username",
        "password": "123456789"
    },
    "name": "David",
    "address": "Baker St"
}
```

my question is, is it possible to just send `"user": 5` instead of sending dictionary in case of POST request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options, either you can use two different serializers for retrieve and create like this

```
class ProfileCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'name', 'address')
```

and

```
class ProfileRetrieveSerializer(ProfileCreateSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
```

and decide which serializer to use in view (hint: override `get_serializer_class` method)

**OR**

Use one serialzer and decide field type according to action type:

```
class ProfileCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'name', 'address')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.context['request'].method == 'GET': # or whatever condition you want to use
            self.fields['user'] = UserSerializer()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do, that you can create your custom serializer fields

```
class CustomForeignKeyField(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset

    def to_representation(self, value):
        value = super().to_representation(value)
        user = User.objects.get(pk=value)
        return UserSerializer(user).data
```

in serializer you can use this fiedls

```
class ProfileSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    user = CustomForeignKeyField(queryset=User.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'name', 'address')
```

it will accept value as int and return the response in json